# Why is Camera2 taking picture so slow?

Tags: android, android-camera2

I'm running Google's Camera2 example code for integrating the camera in my app.

https://github.com/googlearchive/android-Camera2Basic/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2basic/Camera2BasicFragment.java

The code is running fine but it takes 1.1sec /1100ms (on galaxy10+) for one picture from the time the user click of the button until the preview screen.

I saw some suggestions for solutions like 
switch to YUV format, convert it to NV21 and display the image that way, but it lowered time to 1000ms.

Does it make sense?

Comment: Just spitballing, here, but maybe you are waiting until after the button press to open the camera. The `openCamera()` call can take some time; 1000ms isn't surprising. Most apps with a quicker response will already have the camera open, and they're actively showing preview frames, so frames are already streaming at the moment the user hits the shutter.

Comment: I have found it takes a lot of time to rotate the bitmap and save the image. But I didn't find any solution for the rotation.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely the result of to muck work on the main thread, the easy solution for this to add log messages for every action then find during what action you see this message:

```
skipped some number of frames application may be doing to much work on its main thread
```

and offload that method or methods to the ui thread.